# Copy to CUDA GPU Memory from a PCI Device

Tags: linux, windows, cuda, gpgpu, pci

Is there is any way to write to CUDA Device memory from a PCI device. This PCI device is logging data a very fast rate. So attaining the maximum performance, i want to copy the data directly to GPU memory for processing with a host transfer.

I read about RDMA in the CUDA 5.0. How i can transfer the data from PCI to GPU memory using RDMA/GPUDirect.

Please help me in providing some samples for this.

OS I am using are Windows 7 64 bit and CentOS 64 bit
CUDA SDK is 5.0 and GPU is Tesla K20

Comment: Basically by writing/modifying your own device driver for whatever PCI device you are using. The code required to use GPUDirect runs in kernel space, not user space.

Comment: But if i doesn't have the source code of PCI device driver, how can i achieve this.?

Comment: You can't. Your PCI-e device *must* have a driver which uses specific NVIDIA kernel space APIs in order to register pinned memory with the GPU driver and activate the GPUDirect data path. If your device drvier is closed source, then you need to speak to the vendor about adding GPUdirect support.

Answer (score 2):

RDMA for GPUDirect is a feature introduced in Kepler-class GPUs and CUDA 5.0 that enables a direct path for communication between the GPU and a peer device using standard features of PCI Express.
The devices must share the same upstream root complex.
A few straightforward changes must be made to device drivers to enable this functionality.

Please see the [NVIDIA Documentation regarding RDMA for GPUDirect](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/gpudirect-rdma/index.html) for details.

Comment: Technically, RDMA isn't what the question is about. RMDA is *remote* DMA, ie. zero copy across between hosts across a low latency network fabric like Infiniband. GPUDirect is the mechanism by which an RDMA capable network adaptor performs transfers directly to GPU memory across the PCI-e bus. The question is really about the latter mechanism, not the former.